# Convert lang code (ISO 639-1) to country code (ISO 3166-1 alpha-2) in Typescript

Tags: typescript, converters, iso

I got a model file like this :

```
export class LangItem{
  key: string; // ISO 639-1 eg. fr or fr-be
  name: string; //label generated
  countryCode: string; //ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 eg. GB for Great Britain
}
```

The goal is to display a country flag by language code.
The problem is when you have 'en' for 'English' I must get 'gb' or maybe 'us'.
I did not find a npm package for that.
Is there a tool (library) to do this with Typescript similar to this [PHP project](https://github.com/awsmug/i18n-iso-convert) ?

Comment: So, you have a list of `LangItem`s already? If so, isn't this just looking up a `countryCode` based on the `key`?

Comment: @Aplet123, I would like to populate `countryCode` with a package like I´m using [@cospired/i18n-iso-languages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cospired/i18n-iso-languages) to get `name` but in this last case it´s more natural than convert language code by country code because there are some political choices ^^ => 'gb' or 'us'. Maybe I should do my own object.

Comment: It is generally seen as a bad idea, indeed. Representing a language by a flag is very limiting.